# Javascript array push empty when pushing arrays to array with string element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a matrix table from JSON data. So i loop thru the data to create each row. I have the header values in the zones array. First row (header) is built before. Then the first cell in row is a header as well.
The cell is built just fine, but the row has only the first element which is a string. Every cell array that i pushed is not there.

I am wondering if the problem is that the first element in the row array is a string and then i try to push arrays as additional elements.

```
for (i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {
        var row = [];
        // First Cell in row is header
        row[0] = zones[i];
        for (e = 0; e < zones.length; e++) {
            //loop thru the data to create matrix pairs
            val1 = row[0];
            val2 = zones[e];
            search = { 'from zone': val1, 'to zone': val2 };
            result = json.filter((keys => o => keys.every(k => o[k] === search[k]))(Object.keys(search)));
            var cell = [];
            //push the data from result to cell array
            cell.push(result[0]['known']);
            cell.push(result[0]['from']);
            console.log(cell);
            //push the cell to row  
            row.push[cell];
            console.log(row);   
        };
        table.push[row];
    };
```

Comment: `.push[...]` -> `.push(...)`

Comment: THX! and shame on me.